# A database of every guitar chord?

Tags: guitar, chords, alternative-tunings, chord-voicings

For a tool I'm developing, I'd like to have a database of all playable chords (and voicings) on guitar.

"playable" would mean either :

- any position that the human with the biggest stretch could play
- all chords that were ever used (maybe by looking as some tab database ?)
- Any other reasonable criteria

Ideally it would include :

- every voicing (and all inversions and partial chords)
- all common tunings
- It's probably pushing it, but 7 and 8 string chords could be represented too
- proper labels (tuning, chord name, fret numbers or notes played/muted).

I found a lot of lists of chords but they're not exhaustive at all.

As some online tools are able to identify chords and propose alternatives, I thought maybe they'd use a database of some sort ? And if so there might be a version of this database in the open ?

I'll also happily take any hint as to how to build it myself, and If you know an equivalent for another instrument (piano ?) it'll be useful too!

Comment: https://www.hakwright.co.uk/guitarchords/ seems to have done something similar?

Comment: What is the actual question? Requesting resources is supposed to be off-topic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because finding external resources is off topic.

Comment: the hakwright.co.uk / Howard's Big List of Guitar Chords site seems quite extensive, but it looks like it was missing a whole category of chord alternatives - those where you leave out something like the root or the fifth. Or for example in an A11 chord, you look at it as a G/A or G6/A. And it didn't have a x 12 12 12 12 12 for A11 for example. Or sometimes a plain minor triad rooted on the fifth can be enough for the essence of a 9 chord etc. If you're making a program that gives alternatives for chords, consider the actual musical side of it too, not just technical.

Answer (score 1):

The [R library `tabr`](https://github.com/leonawicz/tabr) contains such database:

[image]

It features 4000 chords.

The website given by @top in the comments contains more (40k) and is convenient to scrape.

None of those addresses non standard tuning nor 7 or 8 strings.